# Ubuntu 16.04: Which Nvidia graphics drivers to use (not nouveau)?

Tags: nvidia, hardware

So I want to install the proprietary drivers for my GTX770 and I found conflicting information.

I found this (click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Ubuntu_14.04_and_up)) official Ubuntu page and it seems to me it uses Nvidia drivers that are provided by Ubuntu. I'm guessing I don't need to add additional entry on my repository list to access this.

But I also found this PPA (click [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers)). Multiple internet guides suggests this 3rd-party repository for Nvidia drivers.

So which one to get?

Also Is there some sort of alias to install the latest so I don't have to know which version number to use?

example:

use

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-latest
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

Comment: partly duplicate. still doesn't answer the question which one to use :)

Comment: Doesn't explain why I should not use the other repo

Comment: A PPA has packages that someone uploaded, not always official packages like the packages from the default Ubuntu repositories. Official packages are more stable and secure than unofficial packages.

Comment: @karel I tried the suggested package (from the link you provided) "nvidia-current" and it wants to install nvidia-304 which definitely not the latest.